# JavaScript game loop does not display canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In the following code I program a canvas and display a red block that grows in width as the game progresses. It all worked too! Until, I added a simple game loop to my originally (simpler) game loop. The original just updated, rendered, and restarted. The modern newer one Counts ticks and keeps it running at a consistent speed, no matter how fast the computer/browser. Can anyone explain why this is?
Here is the plain html to set up everything:

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Christmas Town</title>
  <style>
    canvas {
      display: block;
      position: fixed;
      margin: auto;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <script src="game.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

And here is the JavaScript which is supposed to create the canvas and Game Loop:

```
var canvas, context, keyState;
var width = 0;

function tick() {
    "use strict";
    console.log(5 + 6);
    if (width < canvas.getWidth()) {
        width += 1;
    }
}

function render() {
    "use strict";
    context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    context.fillRect(canvas.width, canvas.height, 0, 0);
    context.save();
    context.fillRect(width, 15, 0, 0);
    context.restore();
}

function getTimeMillis() {
    "use strict";
    return window.performance && window.performance.now ? window.performance.now : new Date.getTime();
}

var FPS = 60, startTime, dt = 0, lastTime = getTimeMillis(), targetTime = 1 / FPS;
function frame() {
    "use strict";
    startTime = getTimeMillis();
    dt = dt + Math.min(1, ((startTime - lastTime) / 1000));
    while (dt < targetTime) {
        dt -= targetTime;
        tick();
    }
    render();
    lastTime = startTime;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(frame, canvas);
}

function main() {
    "use strict";
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = 500;
    canvas.height = 500;

    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(frame, canvas);
}

main();
```

The weird part is it's not even logging to the console, and there are no errors! But, I cant seem to figure out why tick is not being called without there being any errors. Please help!

Comment: You've got some brackets missing in a few places.   `window.performance.now() : new Date().getTime()` and `startTime = getTimeMillis();`

Comment: dt is NaN inside frame().. inspect your variable declarations and getTimeMillis() method

Comment: One i'm using brackets as a IDE, thought that was funny...Anyway Changing it now.

Comment: @EricGuan dt is set to 0 it is never NaN.

Comment: It turns into NaN when you assign it to "dt + Math.min(1,...". Probably because you're missing brackets at "startTime = getTimeMillis", needs to be getTimeMillis()

Comment: @EricGuan Oh, sorry man. My bad. Fixing it now.

Comment: Fixed brackets situation, still not displaying canvas or calling method tick().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you wanted but check it out. https://jsfiddle.net/jnsLfwde/

Couple things i changed.

```
context.fillRect( 0, 0, width, 15);
```

The parameters for fillRect are fillRect(x,y,width,height). You had it as (width,height,x,y);

I reversed the less than sign to greater than. Tick() wasn't being called until i did this.

```
(dt > targetTime)
```

You mentioned the animation restarting or something so i added this.

```
if (width < canvas.width) 
    width += 1;
else
    width = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks so much man. I relatively new if you cant tell XD. Anyway Thank YOU.

Comment: Just one more thing. How can I stop dt from turning to NaN but still add it by the min?

Comment: Well the only reason dt = Nan was because you were missing brackets, which caused the javascript to go all crazy. You can do whatever math you'd like on dt, as long as it's valid javascript syntax.

Comment: But I added the brackets but im printing it out and it still returns Nan??

Comment: Are you using the code from my fiddle? or did you just try to change your own, because i didn't post every single change i made in my answer. Also your code doesn't work until you implement @Archer's comment.